# How to integrate a React app with a plain JavaScript app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, webpack

I found a React app that provides the functionality that I would like to add to my plain JavaScript app. Like my existing app, it uses Firebase auth and Firebase Realtime Database, which would allow my users to seamlessly use the new functionality.

Looking at the React app code, it's all JavaScript. The new package.json lists all the React dependencies and other new fields, to be sure. My existing /src folder is flat, whereas the new one contains an index.js and folders for /components, /data, and /sass. My existing app is built with Webpack but the new one just needed `npm run build` and `serve`.

For all these differences, it seems like there could be a practical way to get these two codebases to work together.

How to proceed?

Comment: Sorry but this question is way too vague and unspecific for stackoverflow.

Comment: Once the React app is built, you basically end up with an HTML document that links the React app's script and stylesheet. It's probably easier to add your existing code to that rather than the other way around.

Comment: @ChrisG I think you are right. It's not essential to develop the two apps together. Your suggestion answers the question I was tempted to ask: what would be the *easiest* way to get these apps to work together.